# Is "Cookie" field any different than a http header

Tags: rest, http, cookies

I am a little surprised that this has not been asked before but currently on a project which we are using server side rendering we need call our authenticated API on initial load.

In order to fetch data in an authenticated way we need to send cookies from the server side and to do that when I simply set a header Cookie,

```
fetch(`${ API_SERVER }`, {
     headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Cookie: 'User-Session-Token=' + cookie,
     },
     credentials: 'include',
}
```

and everything works fine. Just wanted to check if there is any security related issues that this might cause, because it is not the browser who sends it and we do it manually.

Comment: How do you get the correct cookie value from? Do you also simulate a login form?

Comment: If an API is intended to be consumed by non-browser clients, it would probably be better to allow for other authentication methods (such as access tokens).

Comment: We are using cors so it can only be accessed by our rendering server. The cookie value is basically passed from browser to server in the request of the initial render. But what I am trying to ask here is if a plain cookie field as an header would create any security breaches or if it is conceptually wrong somehow.

Comment: It is maybe slightly conceptually weird, but not wrong, and many clients (especially in the web scraping field) work that way.

Answer (score -2):

Cookies are first set by the server, and then the browsers send it back in each request to that domain.
If the cookie is not intended to be used by any script, you could set it to be an "HttpOnly" cookie, wich will protect you from cross-site scripting (XSS).

```
Set-Cookie: <name>=<value>[; <Max-Age>=<age>]
[; expires=<date>][; domain=<domain_name>]
[; path=<some_path>][; secure][; HttpOnly]
```

However, the cookie remains vulnerable to cross-site tracing (XST) and cross-site request forgery (XSRF) attacks.

Cookies are been replaced by json web tokens when used for security claims.

"JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard RFC 7519 method for representing claims securely between two parties."

See:

https://jwt.io/